# How to loop through a list and retrieve indices of minimum values but ignore the duplicate in the output list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming. Can someone help me with my query? thanks in advance Say we have a list a = [1, 2, 23, 40, 15, 61, 27, 8, 19, 10]. I would like to loop through the above list (except the first and last elements) and retrieve each element and compare with the previous and next element and return the indices of the minimum values. For example in the above list, compare second element 2 with 1 and 23 and retrieve the index value of 1 (min value). Then compare 23 with 2 and 40 and so on. By doing this i end up with a list that has duplicate indices  that is  [0,1,4,7,7,7]. The correct output list should be [0,1,4,7].

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be understanding incorrectly, but how is the index of `1` `3`? Could you go over your logic a bit more clearly? Also, if you have any attempts we could build off of, that would be great.

Comment: You're on the right track for your problem. Quickest solution to your problem is to use a set instead of a list. Sets can't have duplicates so you'll only get unique values

Comment: sorry  - i have edited the required output list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) here with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [1, 2, 23, 40, 15, 61, 27, 8, 19, 10]

result = set(
    map(
        itemgetter(1),
        (
            min((a[i - 1], i - 1), (e, i), (a[i + 1], i + 1))
            for i, e in enumerate(a[1:-1], start=1)
        ),
    )
)

print(result)
# {0, 1, 4, 7}
```

Which stores the (min, index) pairs first, then takes the index at the end with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

You can also just use a simple list comprehension as well:

```
result = set(
    x[1]
    for x in (
        min((a[i - 1], i - 1), (e, i), (a[i + 1], i + 1))
        for i, e in enumerate(a[1:-1], start=1)
    )
)
```

Or even with just curly brace set syntax:

```
result = {
    x[1]
    for x in (
        min((a[i - 1], i - 1), (e, i), (a[i + 1], i + 1))
        for i, e in enumerate(a[1:-1], start=1)
    )
}
```

If you want a list as the final output, you can wrap [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) on the final result:

```
print(list(result))
# [0, 1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: @BiLAL No worries. If you liked this answer, make sure to mark it as correct as well.